# How can I pass multiple states between views in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently developing an application whereby a list of categories will be displayed. Once a category has been selected, the application will go to the next page which will ask a question about water type. Once the water type has been selected, the app should then display a list of products that match the category and water type that has been selected.

I'm new to React and struggling to understand how managing the state works between pages and components/consts. My code is as follows:

**categories.js**

```
const categories = [
  {
    name: 'Atomic Spectrosocopy',
    imageURL: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Cell Cultures',
    imageURL: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'DNA / RNA Work',
    imageURL: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Electrochemistry',
    imageURL: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Hydroponics',
    imageURL: ''
  },
];

export default categories
```

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import categories from '../components/categories'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <ul>
          {categories.map((cat, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <Link
              to={'/waterType'}
              state={{categorySelected: cat.name}}
              >
                {cat.name}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**waterTypes.js**

```
const waterTypes = [
  {
    name: 'Type 1',
    description: 'xxx'
  },
  {
    name: 'Type 2',
    description: 'xxx'
  },
  {
    name: 'Type 3',
    description: 'xxx'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mains / Portable Supply',
    description: 'xxx'
  },
  {
    name: 'Softened',
    description: 'xxx'
  }
];

export default waterTypes
```

**waterType.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import waterTypes from "../components/waterTypes"

const waterType = ({ location }) => {
  const { state = {} } = location
  const { categorySelected } = state
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Water Types</h1>
      <p>Current category: {categorySelected}</p>
      <ul>
        {waterTypes.map((type, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <Link
            to={'/products'}
            state={
              {categorySelected: {categorySelected}},
              {waterType: type.name}
            }
            >
              {type.name} - {type.description}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default waterType
```

**products.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const products = ({ location }) => {
  const { state = {} } = location
  const { categorySelected, waterType } = state
  console.log(state);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>Current category: {categorySelected}</p>
      <p>Water Type: {waterType}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default products
```

Comment: Have you looked into Single Page React App? You can do this with react router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your React application and here's how I solved it. For **React Router** to work you need your main component wrapped inside *BrowserRouter* which is what I did in **index.js** file.

Then, in the **App.js** file, I created separate routes for navigating between your components. The way you passed **props** down using **Link** component was not correct. That is why your states were undefined. Rest of the code, I have made only minor changes which are trivial for you, I hope.

```
//index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```
//App.js

    import React from "react";
    import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import Home from "./components/Home";
    import Water from "./components/WaterType";
    import Products from "./components/Products";

    import "./App.css";

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/waterType" component={Water} />
            <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

```
//components/Home.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import categories from "./data/categories";

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <ul>
          {categories.map((cat, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <Link
                to={{
                  pathname: "/waterType",
                  name: cat.name,
                }}
              >
                {cat.name}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

```
//components/WaterType.js

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import waterTypes from "./data/waterTypes";

const waterType = ({ location }) => {
  const categorySelected = location.name;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Water Types</h1>
      <p>Current category: {categorySelected}</p>
      <ul>
        {waterTypes.map((type, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: "/products",
                categorySelected: categorySelected,
                waterType: type.name,
              }}
            >
              {type.name} - {type.description}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default waterType;
```

```
//components/Products.js
import React from "react";

const products = ({ location }) => {
  const categorySelected = location.categorySelected;
  const waterType = location.waterType;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>Current category: {categorySelected && categorySelected}</p>
      <p>Water Type: {waterType && waterType}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default products;
```

Here is the folder structure I followed while spinning up this React app.

```
--src
      --App.js
      --index.js
      --components
        --data
        --Home.js
        --Product.js
        --WaterType.js
```

**Note:** Since you are passing down props via Router, please be aware that they are not persistent. You can check that by navigating back and forth between components. If you are navigating linearly, there won't be a problem. You need to find a way to make this persistent once you get this code up running.

Comment: Thanks very much Ajin. Do you have any idea what I should be looking into in order to make the props persistent?

Comment: I am glad it helped, Zakary!. It is a bit tricky. You can do it in several ways. You can use state management libraries like Redux for example. I am afraid I don't have the exact answer for you right now. Maybe you can check this link about [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to learn more and you might find something. Thanks.